# Difference between OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

Can anyone tell me the main difference between OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 3?

In other words, what are the main features in OpenLayers 3?

Comment: It's more than the features that have changed, the entire framework is redesigned.

Answer (score 4):

The features of OpenLayers 3, which distinguish it from OpenLayers 2, seem to be described in a blog post entitled [Hot new features in OpenLayers 3](http://www.camptocamp.com/actualite/hot-new-features-in-openlayers-3/):

> It makes heavy use of the new capabilities of modern Web browsers
>   (Canvas, WebGL) and opens a whole new world of possibilities like
>   client-side vector rendering, integration of 3D data, and many more.

I recommend reviewing the blog posting rather than just the brief summary above.

Comment: thanks polygeo,but the link is not working
http://www.camptocamp.com/actualite/hot-new-features-in-openlayers-3/

Comment: That's weird try clicking here: http://www.camptocamp.com/actualite/hot-new-features-in-openlayers-3/